# HttpContext null in the Signalr Hub file

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, server.mappath

I have a SignalR hub. When the client disconnects, I want to perform a file operation.
To do that, I need to access the `Server.MapPath`.

However, as my Hub class is not an .aspx or a Web Service, there is no `HttpContext` nor request.

I thought of delegating the IO work to the HTTP request handler, but I can not create a WebRequest with a relative URI and I need to be able to deploy the solution in various locations.

How can I be able to get the local path to use in `System.IO` classes from a SignalR?

`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` gives me the location of the IIS worker process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try the following

```
 var path = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null)
                    ? System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/")
                    : System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
```

which uses the hostingenvironment to get the path of the executing application.

Comment: saravanan, this did it!! Thanks heaps

Comment: This works, but I believe you can simply only use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`, it works in all cases. That is, the `null` check and the `Server.MapPath` line could be removed here.